# JSF,Spring,Hibernate Integration.Showing error in applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf

I am trying to integrate `JSF`,Spring and Hibernate.I created bean id for one class in spring .But `applicationContext.xml` file  showing a `ClassNotFound` exception for the class in Spring project.

Comment: make sure you have added the conponent:scan tag in allicationCOntext.xml and have mentioned the correct path

Comment: can you post your applicationContext?

Comment: Add also the stacktrace please.